# CakePHP application in a sub-folder and WordPress in root, how to modify htaccess to make it work?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have WordPress installed in `public_html` i.e, root folder and have CakePHP installed in a sub-folder that is `public_html/CakeApp`. How do I modify htaccess to make this work?

htaccess file in public_html right now reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I access `mydomain.com/CakeApp` it is re-directed to `mydomain.com/CakeApp/users/login` but all it shows is a WordPress 404 error.

Comment: Apparently htacess file was corrupted in the cake application, now it is working just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more condition for WordPress rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/CakeApp [NC]
```

Your .htaccess then should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/CakeApp [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar Can you edit server config or virtual host config? If so -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log to see what is going on -- the rule I have provided **works** for me.

Comment: Hey Thanks Lazyone , I just re-placed the htaccess file and it was working just fine